# Symfony2 Duplicate Entry - but why?

Tags: mysql, symfony, entity, duplicates

I get following exception:

> An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO tasks (task_title, task_description, task_priority, task_type, user) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' with params ["efswedfgvswde", "ewdfweds", "Normal", 14, 13]:
>
> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '13' for key 'UNIQ_505865978D93D649'

Here I insert my form Type into the database:

```
$task = new Task();
$form = $this->createForm(new TaskType(), $task);

$form->handleRequest($request);

if($form->isValid()):

        $em = $this->get('doctrine')->getManager();
        $em->persist($task);
        $em->flush();

        return  $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('add_task'));

endif;
```

This is the field USER in my Task Entity:

```
/**
 * @var User
 * @Assert\Type(type="Seotool\MainBundle\Entity\User")
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="User")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $user;
```

Why is it NOT possible to add 2 entrys into the Table "Task" with same values of field "user" ? Actually in my database there is one entry with user value = 13. When I add another entry in my database with user = 13 I get this exception. Why is it? I have not defined, that User is unique ?!

Thats ID from User Entity:

```
/**
 * @var integer $id
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id()
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;
```

Comment: You seem to be wanting a oneToMany rather than a oneToOne. a OneToOne means that each object can be connected to only one of the other object, where as you are trying to connect 2 (or more) tasks to 1 user.

Comment: Now I'm fully confused...I get one error after another.... -.-

Comment: When i have 2 Tasks - Task ID 1 and Task ID 2. Task ID 1 has User ID 1 but Task ID 1 has also User ID 2. Task Id 2 has only User Id 2. I want now to add into TaskDone when a task is done from a user. So I add TaskDone -> id 1 | task id 1 | user id 1 | AND id 2 | task id 1 | user id 2 . So every task with a user can be set as done. Is this then OnetoOne ? Or ManytoMany or OnetoMany or ManytoOne ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have wrong association mapping as @Qoop stated.

*One user* can have *many tasks* - that translates to OneToMany association from User entity.
*Many tasks* may belong to *one user* - that translates to ManyToOne association from Task entity.

Provided code indicates that association is *unidirectional* (there's no `$tasks` field in User entity) so there's only need for **ManyToOne** mapping from Task entity.

Your mapping should look like this:

```
/**
 * @var User
 * @Assert\Type(type="Seotool\MainBundle\Entity\User")
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $user;
```

You can learn more about associations in Doctrine [here](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html).
There's also similar problem on StackOverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7704933/symfony2-onetoone-relationship-becomes-either-a-unique-index-or-a-foreign-key).